# posted images in wall disappear

Tags: facebook, image

i'm posting some images using the following command:

```
    $url_facebook  = "https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?message=".$messaggio."&attachment={\"name\":\"".$title."\",\"href\":\"".$action_link."\",\"caption\":\"".$caption."\",\"description\":\"".$description."\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"".$image."\",\"href\":\"".$action_link."\"}]}&action_links=[{\"text\":\"".$link_name."\",\"href\":\"".$action_link."\"}]&target_id=".$target_uid."&uid=".$source_uid."&".$site_token."";
    simplexml_load_file("".$url_facebook."");
```

the image i post in the wall (a group) is generated on the fly from PHP.

this is what happens:

- i generate an image and save it to a folder
- i post it with the code upon
- i exit from the script
- the next time a run the script (each hour) i delete all the old
  created images , than repeat wath sayid upon

i noticed that the images just when published, are present and existing on the FB wall

BUT

the next time i launch the script (and so the images are deleted from my site) they disappear also from facebook

i understood that the images where uploaded to facebook, so they were not needed anymore on my space....

isn't so ?

i've this doubt also because, if i see on the red x on facebook (in the place of the images)

and i right click "proprerties", i can read :

```
"https://s-platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=164286063695472&v=1&size=z&cksum=17f253305254403324260843c7a6989a&src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.graficisismici.it%2FV6_00%2Ffacebook%2Ffacebook_link_285790.jpg%3F285790"
```

so it's seem that it's really a link to the original image
can you solve my doubt ?

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile I modified the script to use the new Graph Api

```
<?php

    $user = null;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

    if($user == 0) {

            /**
             * Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
             * assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
             * JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
             * 
             * The parameters:
             * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
             * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
             */

            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('scope' => "publish_stream"));

            echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");
    } else {
        $user_message = "Message";
        $titolo = "Titolo";
        $caption = "Caption";
        $link_name = "Link Name";
        $action_link = "Action Link";
        $testo = "Text";
        $image = "Image Link";

        $target_uid = "XXXXXXXX"; // ID where to publish    

        //HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream
        $post_url = '/'.$target_uid.'/feed';

            try {
                    $params = array(
                        'message' => $user_message,
                        'name' => $titolo,
                        'caption' => $caption,
                        'link' => $action_link,
                        'description' => $link_name,
                        'picture' => $image,
                        'actions' => array(
                                            array(
                                                'name' => $testo,
                                                'link' => $action_link
                                            )
                                        )  
                    );

                    $post = $facebook->api($post_url,"POST",$params);
                }
                catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                   $result = $e->getResult();
                }

    }

?>
```

I just would like to have a clarification about the image question.
Does the image have to still exist ? 
Or once posted, I can delete them, as they still live on Fb ?

My questione born from the fact that i see (while using the old script in the top of this post) on the error log of my site a lof of row of 404 error (related to the missed images searched from Fb)

Answer (score 0):

> i understood that the images where uploaded to facebook, so they were not needed anymore on my space....

This is not the case.  Facebook simply caches your content in their CDN.  If you delete the source photos, when the content falls out of their cache, their attempt to refresh / re-fill the cache will fail and your users will get a broken image icon.

> Does the image have to still exist ? Or once posted, I can delete them, as they still live on Fb ?

You should not delete them.